# Locking a Java object or a Java method in a WebLogic Cluster

Tags: java, locking, weblogic, cluster-computing

I'm running a JavaEE Weblogic 10 Cluster.

I'm looking for a good design to lock an entity accross the differents JVM of my cluster.
Is there a kind of *synchronized* keyword, accross differents JVM?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [Terracotta Core](http://www.terracotta.org) does....